# Quadratic factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is a general rule of thumb that we can use to check whether a quadratic expression can be factored without the use of the quadratic formula since using the quadratic formula can be time consuming in exam situations?

Is it even possible to tell whether an expression will require application of the quadratic formula even before beginning to factor it?

Comment: Well, you could always check that the discriminant is non-negative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. There is the "AC Method" which is somewhat faster than quadratic formula when it works (there is also completing the square). If $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and the coefficients are integers, then if you can find integers r and s so that $rs = ac$ and $r + s = b$ then $f(x) = ax^2 + rx + sx + c$ which can be factored by grouping.

Comment: The rational root theorem is useful for polynomials with integer coefficients. The point is not so much "check all rational roots" but that it gives some obvious candidates to quickly check; if one of them happens to be a root, then the other root can be found by inspection.

Comment: +1 for the rational root theorem, which is very easy to use in an exam situation.

Comment: I (subjectively) object to the comment @MattiP., since use of the discriminant can be construed as a *disguised* use of the quadratic formula.  I suggest that you abandon any attempt to avoid the use of the quadratic formula short of an initial attempt to factor the 2nd degree polynomial.  For example, you can avoid applying the quadratic formula (equation) to the equation $0 = x^2 + 3x + 2$ by factoring the 2nd degree polynomial (in your head) and thereby concluding that $(x+2)(x+1) = x^2 + 3x + 2.$

Comment: I (subjectively) object to the comment of @Countable, as well as the factoring method inherent in the tail end of my previous comment, for two reasons: [1] To some extent, these methods involve *trial and error*, which is not recommended. [2] To the extent that alternative methods are employed *systematically* rather than by *trial and error*, you end up using the same math theory inherent in the quadratic formula, simply in a somewhat haphazard manner.  ...see next comment.

Comment: In my opinion, best is to simply embrace the quadratic formula and regard alternatives as a fool's errand.  The only downside is the occasional situations that involve a quadratic that will bend to *lucky guesses*.  Most problems are not of that nature.  Personally, when confronted with a quadratic, I normally invest 60-90 seconds attempting a *lucky guess*.  If that fails, I then immediately resort to the quadratic formula (equation).

Comment: I mean @user2661923 It is fairly common to come across a polynomial like $x^2 + -x -6$ which one can just think of a factorization for using AC in a few seconds, so often no trial and error even needed, I am just saying that if you need quick solutions, it is very fast and not that difficult. You really don't need to be "lucky" for this, it is just a matter of if the polynomial is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and looks like it can probably be done with AC, it only takes a few seconds to think of the solution a lot of the time.

Comment: @Countable This is why I normally invest 60-90 seconds looking for an alternative, before reverting to the quadratic equation.  Also, even in those situations where an alternative works, the *discriminant* is usually *nice*, so you haven't really saved that much time/effort over immediately using the quadratic equation.

Comment: @user2661923 60 to 90 seconds is a lot, I don't know what polynomials you are trying to factor. For me it is (i) contemplate for maybe 4 seconds if it can be done with AC, if so, use AC and it takes maybe 3-5 seconds. Otherwise use quad form or completing the square. It is really a waste of time to use quad form on say $x^2 + 5x + 6$ for instance. So I don't know what your point is, you might just want to practice it a bit, it saves a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: @Countable My point is that in my opinion, until the math student has dealt with (say) 200 quadratic equations, best is to simply always use the quadratic equation.  Only then, after gaining a lot of experience and thereby having one's intuition stretched, might it be helpful to look at alternatives.

Comment: @user2661923 I don't completely disagree but the other thing is that if you don't practice it, you won't get better at it, and really the quadratic formula is the easiest one, so it needs the least amount of practice. Of course yes though I agree that you need some experience to be really fast with AC usually (I don't know if its 200 but a few at least for most students).

Comment: For more info on the rational root thereom see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem#Proofs

Answer (score 1):

All second degree equations can be factored but we might ask: Are the factors real or complex? Are they rational or irrational? Another answer mentioned the discriminant.

If $\quad b^2-4ac\lt0\quad $ the factors are complex (with an imaginary parts).

If $\quad b^2-4ac\ge 0\quad $ the factors are real numbers

If $\quad b^2-4ac\qquad$ is a perfect square, the factors are rational.

If you want to "find" the roots (factors) (if they exist) without the quadratic formula, you can apply the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). In it, you just try all of the rational numbers composed of factors of the first and last terms, dividing using synthetic division, and seeing if they divide without remainder into the original quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The criterion is to check whether the discriminant $$b^2-4ac$$ of the equation $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ is a perfect square (assuming the coefficients are integers). The equation can be factorised in $\mathrm Q$ if and only if this is the case. You can quickly check whether the square root of the discriminant is an integer if you're allowed a calculator.